# Mutating list of instantiated objects in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm attempting to clean up my view by moving Rails' sanitizer method to a helper, but it's not producing the desired result. So below is what my index action looks like. I know it's ugly and not very OOP, but I simplified it down so I could follow what was happening when debugging.

I'm attempting to loop through all the sources' attributes, running the sanitizer on any attribute that is a non-empty string, replacing original strings with the sanitized strings (transform_values!), and writing over the original @sources (map!).

I tried storing them in different variables than `@sources` and using `.each` instead of `.map!` but the sanitized values don't make it through.

```
def index
  @sources = Source.all
  @sources.map! { |source| 
    source.attributes.transform_values! { |attr|
      attr.blank? || !attr.is_a?(String) ? attr 
      : ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(attr) } }
end
```

However, after examining my list of sources in the view, it's removing the source instances and instead returning a nondescript array of hashes. I can loop through these, but I can't call specific attributes like `source.author` which is not great.

Here's some images for reference. The first one is what it should look like and second is what I'm currently getting

[Unsanitized sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTALV.png)

[Sanitized sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcCAm.png)

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize all strings like that in the controller? Isn't that a view responsibility? Especially because in the view should know if a value is a string and usually escapes strings automatically.

Comment: `transform_values` returns a `Hash` and `map!` replaces the current object with the block response. What exactly did you expect?

Comment: @spickermann - One of my other models has over 20 attributes. I'm trying to DRY up the view so I don't do sanitize(object, tags: %w(strong, sup, sub, etc)) as many times. If you have a better idea, I'm all ears

Comment: @engineersmnky - Your response isn't helpful at all

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize only a few tags? Are html tags generally allowed and possible on all that attributes?

Comment: @emplumb I am asking what your expectation is. No one can help you without understanding your expectation which is very unclear at the moment. I am sorry if I somehow offended you when all I was doing is explaining what you refer to as *"...a nondescript array of hashes"*. As for the sanitation this is the default behavior and thus probably is not required at all, however I still do not understand your goal or your implementation so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @spickermann - There's only a handful that should ever be needed for my use case. Isn't it good practice to only whitelist the ones you need? Or does it really make no difference?

Comment: @engineersmnky - I thought I explained my purpose, but I suppose it could have been clearer. Instead of sanitizing the sources in the view, I want to sanitize behind the scenes so my view isn't cluttered

Comment: There is no need to manually sanitize strings in Rails unless you need something special like not sanitizing everything but only specific html tags. Therefore your question is about unclear. Would you mind posting some examples of your data, your view and your expected output?

Comment: @emplumb my point was you do not need to sanitize this data. The sanitation is default you actually have to intentionally avoid it, using things like `raw` or `html_safe`, not implement it.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but thank you both for your input. I see now that I was approaching this problem incorrectly. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map!` replaces each item in the array with the result of the block. This is not what you intend to do, because you just want to mutate the items, not replace them with something else. Use a plain `each` instead of `map!` would do the trick.

On another side, sanitization is actually a responsibility of the view (that’s why it’s defined in a helper). If you need to sanitize often with the same argument, define your own helper:

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def sany(str)
    sanitize(str, %w[...])
  end
end

<%= sany(source.some_attr) %>
```

You could also set the default sanitization options following the documentation:

```
# In config/application.rb
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ['strong', 'em', 'a']
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = ['href', 'title']
```